# why --user used constantly in curl examples?

Tags: wallet, server

```
curl --user myusername --data-binary '{"jsonrpc": "1.0", "id":"curltest", "method": "encryptwallet", "params": ["my pass phrase"] }' -H 'content-type: text/plain;' http://127.0.0.1:8332/
```

https://bitcoincore.org/en/doc/0.16.0/rpc/wallet/encryptwallet/
what's it?

looks  like username:password but why then it's called 'myusername'

Answer (score 1):

The RPC interface is an authenticated interface - it requires a username and password to use it. By specifying `--user` with the RPC username, `curl` will prompt you to enter the passphrase before sending the request. `myusername` is just a placeholder for the RPC username that you actually use.

Note that this username and passphrase is unrelated to the wallet. The wallet does not have usernames, and the passphrase is specific to the wallet and provided in the RPC, not in HTTP headers.

Comment: it constantly fails so i do not know what's it. i use `http://uname:password@127....` stuff

Comment: Fails how? You could add `-v` to get verbose output to get more info on what is going on. The example command works for me.